# Ошибка 403 при Get запросе Java

Tags: java, get

Вот Get запрос использующий apache httpclent. Тут все работает.

```
public static String getJsonApache(String url) {
        String data="";
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                data = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent(), "cp1251");
            }
            else System.out.println("Error");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Но при использовании стандартной библиотеки Java, прилетает ошибка 403 - доступ закрыт.

```
public static String getJSON(String urle) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urle);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        con.connect();

        int resp = con.getResponseCode();
        if(resp == 200) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ответ сервера: " + resp);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
}
```

Я понимаю что нужно прописать какую-то настройку для `con`,но какую именно?

Comment: Запрос через прокси идет? Если да, то нужно еще указать данные прокси: https.proxyHost и https.proxyPort, а так же https.proxyUser и https.proxyPassword. И отдельно сертификат проимпортировать в JVM.

Comment: Нет, прокси не использую. Оказалось что нужен был сертификат, а Apache его видимо сам ипортировал.